# PHP Echo Input value inside slashes breake down html slashes system

Tags: php, html

When I use different slashes in input value html slashes system is broking.

PHP

```
$val = "Brother's team say: " . '"Hello Man".';
```

HTML

```
<input value='<?php echo $val;  ?>' >
```

OUTPUT IS :

```
<input value='Brother's team say: "Hello Man".' >
```

EDIT:::

I change input to textarea. Textarea is working.

```
 <textarea> <?php echo $val; ?> </textarea>
```

Comment: <input value='Brother\'s team say: \"Hello Man\".'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

HTML is best written with double quote.  Although single quotes can be used, sometimes the results are not as predicable.

For example:

```
<?php
$val = "Brother's team say: " . '"Hello Man".';
?>
<!-- testing single qouted values  -->
<input value='<?php echo $val;  ?>' ><br>
<input value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($val);  ?>' ><br>
<input value='<?php echo htmlentities($val);  ?>' ><br>
<!-- testing double quoted values -->
<input value="<?php echo $val;  ?>" ><br>
<input value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($val);  ?>" ><br>
<input value="<?php echo htmlentities($val);  ?>" ><br>
```

Will output the following:

Brother

Brother

Brother

Brother's team say:

Brother's team say: "Hello Man".

Brother's team say: "Hello Man".

Only the last two are correct. The answer is to use either htmlentities or htmlspecialchars AND correct the html line:

Old:

```
<input value='<?php echo $val_double;  ?>' >
```

Correct:

```
<input value="<?php echo  htmlspecialchars($val_double);  ?>" ><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Solution Change Input to Textarea
I change input to textarea. Textarea is working. 
But this is not most accurate solution.

HTML-PHP

```
<textarea> <?php echo $val; ?> </textarea>
```